# Bounty doesn't shown on reputation graph selection

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, reputation-graph

Hi,

I found a problem with my [reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241776/developer?tab=reputation). If I select a time interval then it doesn't show my bounties. On the following **screen-shot** you may see a selected interval containing 500 bounty, but the listing at right side of the graph doesn't show it.

It seems to be a regression because bounties was shown 2 or more months ago. See also related old question ["The Reputation Graph is wildly inaccurate with reputation losses"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59159/the-reputation-graph-is-wildly-inaccurate-with-reputation-losses-bounty-awards) from Jul 31 '10.

[image: interval doesn't show my bounties]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounty awards were missing from the graph - this is now fixed.